# Twincat, how to virtualise Ethercat between two hyper V pc

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, twincat, ethercat

I have created 2 Hyper V machine running windows 11 and Twincat .29, i have then created a NIC on both the virtual PC´s. to run Ethercat, and installed beckohff RT driver on it.
All that works.
The NIC dont have any connection to the hardware NIC, all is virtualise.

Now my question is, how to set the virtual NIC to tranfed a Ethercat telegram.

1. i can't turn the hyper V switch into a TSN switch, or is that possible?
2. Can i get the 2 virtual PC to, think there is a "network cable" between them, so there is no switch, like in real life ethercat.

Comment: I think you can connect two Ethernet ports with each other by bridging them. To do so, go to Network Settings in Windows, and select the two Ethernet ports, right click and choose bridge.

Comment: Thx Roald, but it is on 2 separated machines.

Comment: The you probably need a real cable between them.

Comment: I believe that you are right. :-)